# I wrote some codes in java. I just used if-else, function, and recursive method. How can I do this better?

Tags: java

Here is my code. Let me describe what I do here. I have 7kg soaps, and 2kg soaps. And I have total kg that mean how many kg soaps I need.
I should use 7kg soaps first, if there is no need I shouldnt use 2 kg soaps. If I dont use any 2kg soaps, it must return -1, if i use 2 kg soaps it must return the amount of how many of them I use.
I have prepareCargoPacket(int 7kg soap, int 2 kg soap, int totalKg)

for example; prepareCargoPacket(2,2,16); return 1 since i use 2kg soaps one time.
prepareCargoPacket(1,3,10); return -1 cause i cant get 10kg from these values, and i cant use 2kg soaps

```
package com.bit32.cargocalculation;

public class CargoCalculation {


/**
 * Returns how many 2Kgs soap we need to use
 * 
 * @param count7Kg -> count of how many 7Kgs soaps we have
 * @param count2Kg -> count of how many 2Kgs soaps we have
 * @param totalKg  -> the needed Kg I have to get 
 * @return
 */


public int prepareCargoPacket(int count7Kg, int count2Kg, int totalKg) {
    
    int solution = -1; // if there is no answer, or no need for 2Kgs soaps, the answer is -1
    
// if we have 7Kg ones many more than totalKg, we should decrease it to get from 2Kgs.      
    if (7*count7Kg > totalKg) {
        return prepareCargoPacket(count7Kg-1, count2Kg, totalKg); 
        
// if we have enough 7Kgs that are equal to totalKg, we will not use 2Kgs.          
    } else if (7*count7Kg == totalKg) {
        return solution; // solution = -1
        
// if we have 7Kgs less than totalKg        
    } else {
        
// currentTotalKg is equal to the amount of Kg that we can use for 2Kgs     
        int currentTotalKg;
        for (int i = count7Kg; i>=0; i--) {
            
            currentTotalKg = totalKg - 7*i;
            
            if (currentTotalKg % 2 == 0 && count2Kg*2 >= currentTotalKg) {
                solution = currentTotalKg/2;
                break;

            } 
            return solution;
        }
                    
    }
    
    return solution;

}
```

}

Comment: If the code above is working and you just want suggestions on how to improve it, then the question would be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on CodeReview

Comment: yes it is working. I just wanted to help about how to make it better. Thanks @OHGODSPIDERS